# how to get the output of a terminal command into a C string

Tags: c, terminal

I currently have a method where I pipe the terminal command I want into a file, and then read from the file... so if the command I want is `cat *` then i would do something like `system("cat * > test")` and then open the `test` file to read it into a string.

I want to be able to do this without making a file but I can't think of any other methods to do this.

Comment: How about listing the directory and opening the files, using the appropriate calls? Like [`opendir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and [`fopen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen)?

Comment: ok thanks for pointing me towards that, popen seems perfect

Comment: Have a look at [popen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen).